# Return lists giving a range of dates

Tags: python, matrix

I have a list in a txt file like this:

```
Series;Type;Year;Ranking
Chernobyl;Drama;2019;9.4
True Detective;Crime;2014;9.0
Fargo;Crime;2014;8.9
Friends;Comedy;1994;8.9
When They See Us;Drama;2019;8.9
Stranger Things;Drama;2016;8.8
Black Mirror;Drama;2011;8.8
```

I managed to read the contents and insert them into a 2d list with the following code:

```
f = open("Series_Ranking.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    Series.append(line.split(";"))
```

Which returns this:

```
[['Series', 'Type', 'Year', 'Ranking'], ['Chernobyl', 'Drama', '2019', '9.4\n'], ['True Detective', 'Crime', '2014', '9.0\n'], ['Fargo', 'Crime', '2014', '8.9\n'], ['Friends', 'Comedy', '1994', '8.9\n'], ['When They See Us', 'Drama', '2019', '8.9\n'], ['Stranger Things', 'Drama', '2016', '8.8\n'], ['Black Mirror', 'Drama', '2011', '8.8\n']]
```

What I'm trying to do now is filter the list giving a specific range.
For example print only Series of the year between 2014 and 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a list comprehension:

```
all_series = [['Chernobyl', 'Drama', '2019', '9.4\n'], ['True Detective', 'Crime', '2014', '9.0\n'], ['Fargo', 'Crime', '2014', '8.9\n'], ['Friends', 'Comedy', '1994', '8.9\n'], ['When They See Us', 'Drama', '2019', '8.9\n'], ['Stranger Things', 'Drama', '2016', '8.8\n'], ['Black Mirror', 'Drama', '2011', '8.8\n']]
filtered = [n for n in all_series if int(n[2]) <= 2019 and int(n[2]) >= 2014]
print(filtered)
```

This will print out a filtered list, only containing series that were released before or on 2019 and after or on 2014.

You can loop over the list containing all series. But this will only work if the first list is not there, `['Series', 'Type', etc...]`

You could also check if the year matches your criteria and then append it, as such:

```
f = open("Series_Ranking.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in range(1, len(lines)):
    if int(lines[line][2]) <= 2019 and int(lines[line][2]) >= 2014:
        Series.append(lines[line].split(";"))
```

Here I used Len() instead of just looping over the list to skip over the first list which are the labels.

Comment: With your last code i get an error message
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @R.Teixeira I fixed the bug. I tried indexing the variable instead of the list `lists` at index `list`. The code in the question now should be working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter, you can use the `filter` function!

```
series = [['Series', 'Type', 'Year', 'Ranking'], ['Chernobyl', 'Drama', '2019', '9.4\n'], ['True Detective', 'Crime', '2014', '9.0\n'], ['Fargo', 'Crime', '2014', '8.9\n'], ['Friends', 'Comedy', '1994', '8.9\n'], ['When They See Us', 'Drama', '2019', '8.9\n'], ['Stranger Things', 'Drama', '2016', '8.8\n'], ['Black Mirror', 'Drama', '2011', '8.8\n']]
criteria = lambda show: int(show[2]) >= 2014 and int(show[2]) <= 2019
filtered = filter(criteria, series[1:])
print(filtered)
```

prints:

```
[['Chernobyl', 'Drama', '2019', '9.4\n'], ['True Detective', 'Crime', '2014', '9.0\n'], ['Fargo', 'Crime', '2014', '8.9\n'], ['When They See Us', 'Drama', '2019', '8.9\n'], ['Stranger Things', 'Drama', '2016', '8.8\n']]
```

If the data were a little cleaner, then the header wouldn't be the first item in the list, the years wouldn't be strings, and the items might be `namedtuple`s instead of `list`s. In this case, you'd be able to write the following instead:

```
criteria = lambda show: show.year >= 2014 and show.year <= 2019
filtered = filter(criteria, series)
```